# OLAP connection error

Tags: c#, devexpress, windows-7-x64, olap

I am using: Windows 7 x64; Visual Studi 2010 (C#); .NET 3.5; DevExpress 12.1.

---

When I am using direct connection with PivotGrid everything is OK, but when I trying to use proxy, I am getting following error:

> Couldn't connect to the Analysis Services: The connection is not open

Other .NET network-based functions are working fine.

Comment: UPD. [That](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/497618/RuntimeplusImpersonationplusforplusOLAPplusDatabas) is not working for me.

Comment: What type of proxy do you mean? AS-proxy, or network(http/socks5) proxy? Can you show part of code(not related to business-logic of your application, stripped/obfuscated maybe) where you had encountered this error?

Comment: `PivotGridAdomdDataSource adoDataSource = new PivotGridAdomdDataSource();
adoDataSource.ConnectionString = report.GetConnectionString();`

Comment: public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            if (ErrorMessage != null) return null;

            return new StringBuilder().Append("provider=MSOLAP;")
                                      .Append(GetCubeStorage(this.IsTestMode))
                                      .Append("cube name=\"").Append(CubeName)
                                      .Append("\";query timeout=")
                                      .Append(QUERY_TIMEOUT)
                                      .Append(";connect timeout=")
                                      .Append(10000)

Comment: .Append(";")
                                      .Append(/*Domain, login, password*/)
                                      .ToString();
        }

Comment: I am sorry, StackOverflow is not allow me to answer to my own questions. :)

Comment: You should be able to edit your question.